# Wait Till Text Present In Text Field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In webdriver, how to ask to webdriver to wait until text is present in text field.

actually i have one kendo text field whose values comes from database which takes some time to load. Once it load i can proceed further.

please help on this

Answer (score 25):

You can use WebDriverWait. From docs example:

```
 (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.findElement(...).getText().length() != 0;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use `WebDriverWait`. From docs example:
above ans using `.getTex()` this is not returning text from input field

use `.getAttribute("value")` instead of `getText()`

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(...).getAttribute("value").length() != 0;
    }
});
```

tested 
100% working
hope this will help

Answer (score 11):

A one liner that works and uses lambda function.

```
wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) driver -> driver.findElement(By.id("elementId")).getAttribute("value").length() != 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `WebDriverWait (org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)` and `ExpectedCondition (org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions)` objects

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("element_id"), "The Text"));
```

Comment: textToBePresentInElement() is now deprecated

Comment: How to check it if it would be random text? Is it possible to check the length of the text?

Comment: @SamuelRondeau-Millaire is there any substitute now, if it has been deprecated?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple method in which you need to pass driver object webelement in which text is going to come and the text which is goint to come.

```
public static void waitForTextToAppear(WebDriver newDriver, String textToAppear, WebElement element) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(newDriver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, textToAppear));
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, it looks for text nodes within the given `WebElement`, i.e., other element's texts, text between elements, and so on. The question is about text in an input, so it needs to be `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for sending text to input:

```
  public void sendKeysToElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement webElement, String text) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Configuration.standardWaitTime);
    try {

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.and(
                ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBeNotEmpty(webElement, "value")),
                ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement)));

        webElement.sendKeys(text);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(webElement, text));

        activeElementFocusChange(driver);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Configuration.printStackTraceException(e);
    }
}

WebElement nameInput = driver.findElement(By.id("name"));
sendKeysToElement(driver, nameInput, "some text");
```

Comment: While the code you've provided may include the answer to the OP's problem - the post is not very useful without an explanation of how you've solved their issue.