# What ExpectedConditions should i use in order to

Tags: selenium

So sometimes when i want to `click` on WebElement i am using `elementToBeClickable`.
Now when i want to `get text` etc. i have 2 options (maybe more ???) that i usually use:

1. `presenceOfElementLocated` - An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page.
2. `visibilityOfElementLocated` - An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.

My questions:

1. Whats the different between the both ?
2. When i want to get text from element/attribute maybe should i use another `ExpectedCondition` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presenceOfElementLocated` would just wait for the presence of an element in the DOM tree.

`visibilityOfElementLocated` would not only ensure that an element is present, but also check if the element *is displayed*. The logic behind the visibility determination is described here:

- [Element Displayedness](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness)

Which Expected Condition to use is not that simple as in case of `elementToBeClickable` and a button needed to be clicked - in this case  depends on the actual use case - how the desired element is loaded, is it loaded with the text, or the text is set later and dynamically etc.

---

There is also [`textToBePresentInElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-) which might be more suitable, but it requires you to know a part of the element's text.

And, there is always an option to write a *custom Expected Condition* - for instance, you can [wait for any text to be present in element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657053/771848).

Comment: So this bather using visibilityOfElementLocated ?

Comment: @davidhol added some more information to the answer. Hope that helps.