# Selenium WebDriver C# Wait for Any Text

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, wait

How to explicit wait until any text is present in IWebElement .Text property

```
/// <summary>
/// Work
/// </summary>
/// <param name="by"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IWebElement WaitUntilAnyTextIsPresentInElementValue(By by)
{
    IWebElement element = _driver.FindElement(by);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(by).GetAttribute("value") != string.Empty);

    return element;
}

/// <summary>
/// Don't Work
/// </summary>
/// <param name="by"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IWebElement WaitUntilAnyTextIsPresentInElementText(By by)
{
    IWebElement element = _driver.FindElement(by);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(by).Text != string.Empty);

    return element;
}
```

First method working fine, second don't wait...

```
IWebElement dsfTest = WaitUntilAnyTextIsPresentInElementValue(By.Id("dsfTest"));

//It wait 30 seconds, if text is found try to Assert, if not throw TimeOutException as expected...
Assert.AreEqual("Test", dsfTest.Text);


IWebElement dsfTest = WaitUntilAnyTextIsPresentInElementText(By.Id("dsfTest"));

//Try to assert without wait (sometimes it will work)... (i know that it doesn't wait because it don't throw TimeOutException and Assert fail because text still empty)
Assert.AreEqual("Test", dsfTest.Text);
```

................................................................................

This one work, but need to pass a specific text to watch for...

```
public IWebElement WaitUntilTextIsPresentInElementText(By by, string text)
{
    IWebElement element = _driver.FindElement(by);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(element, text));

    return element;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean don't wait??? describe in detail

Comment: Text cannot be empty.  So try this : wait.Until(d => (string)d.FindElement(by) != string.Empty);

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i mean it should wait until text is present or throw the timeout exception If exceed 30 seconds and nothing is found

Comment: Could you add the html of the element when text == string.Empty?

Comment: @Rieth so how did you examine that your method is wrong, is this method  not working for all element for this condition or only some specific element??? if only specific, make sure element has text.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur The element has text, i tried diferent elements..

Comment: @Rieth then what happened when you tried same method on different element to waiting for text??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur please check the added info

Comment: @Rieth Try this `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(IWebElement, "text to be present"));`. It will wait until the text is present in the IWebElement

Comment: @Sudeepthi I dont want to wait for specific text... Just any text... Can  i use some kind of wildcard ?

Comment: @Rieth Wait until length of element is not empty. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656252/wait-till-text-present-in-text-field). Hope it might help.

Comment: @Sudeepthi it fail