# Wait until text of a webelement IS an exact, given text

Tags: java, selenium, wait

In Java, Selenium, you can wait until a text is present in a `webelement` (with a `WebDriverWait`):

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(webelement, expectedMessage));
```

However, what do you do when you don't want just expectedMessage to be **present** in the element (= expectedMessage being a substring of  webelement.getText()), but to be **the exact text** of the webelement (=expectedMessage being the same string as webelement.getText())?

Selenium does provide the function:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(locator, expectedMessage));
```

but when you have gathered webelements by the locators with @FindBy in your page class, it's awkward to make the locators again directly accessible to test classes.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait Till Text Present In Text Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656252/wait-till-text-present-in-text-field)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own ExpectedCondition:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitForTextInElementEquals(WebElement elm, String text) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                String elementText = elm.getText();
                return elementText.equals(text);
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException var3) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("text ('%s') to be present in element %s", text, elm);
        }
    };
}
```

Which you can use just like the ExpectedConditions already in WebDriverWait:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, 30, 1000);
    wait.until(waitForTextInElementEquals(foo, bar));
```

Comment: JeffC: So, where does it exist and what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

There's another simpler solution:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, waitForElementTimeout).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(webelement, "text", expected));
```

Tested with selenium 3.8.1.