# Selenium wait when data loads in element from a calculation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Consider this scenario:

We have to perform `element.getText()` over an element for which data is coming up from a calculation .

On page load element is present but data takes 5 seconds to load.

Explicit wait and Implicit wait both will look whether element is present or not which is true from 1 to 5 seconds and they will execute returning me null text.

What wait we can apply on this case ??
Or the only solution left is `Thread.sleep(5000)`

Comment: are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657053

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this. It didn't actually solved my problem but a workaround .

Answer (score 0):

Using this way you can solve your problem

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code.
i had the same issue before i tried to trick him with unnessacary code and it worked.

```
this.browser.waitForVisible(locator);
this.browser.getText(locator);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the current situation. If in your application, the element is present with default value, and we need to wait for the value appear, then we can create Explicite wait for the value changed. In this case, the worse situation is that the calculated value is the same with the default value, then we need to wait for the whole timeout specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable("element locator"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another waiting method to check if any query is still active.
And if that returns 0 -> which means the text you want is calculated.

```
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 20);
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation;
expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driverjs) {
        return (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return (window.jQuery != null) && (jQuery.active === 0);");
    }
};
driverWait.until(expectation);
```

Which would result in waiting for the ajax load.