# Java - Selenium wait for text to appear in wysiwyg

Tags: java, selenium, wysiwyg

i have been trying to wait for any text to appear in wysiwyg.
here is my code

```
           WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 70);
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>(){
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver f) {
                WebElement iframeMsg = f.findElement(By.className("cke_wysiwyg_frame"));        
                f.switchTo().frame(iframeMsg);
                WebElement body = f.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
                return body.getText().length() != 0;

            }            
        });
```

from this link:
[Wait Till Text Present In Text Field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15657053/6022774)

but its not working(program does not wait)

```html
<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_63" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true">
 <html dir="ltr" lang="en"><head></head>
 <body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="false"><p><br></p>
 </body>
 </html>


</iframe>
```

this website generate content, which takes about 30 ~ 70 sec with arg of  45 sec.
i want to wait for that content which will show up in body of wysiwyg. Currently in using Thread.sleep(70000)

Comment: Try trimming the body text. There might be whitespace there.

Comment: At which line are you waiting for the text?

Comment: @DebanjanB in wait.until i guess

Comment: @Antoniossss I am still not sure what is OP trying to achieve in the entire `function()` within which he is using `f.switchTo().frame(iframeMsg)`. With EC it would have been much more simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often have this problem in selenium and nothing I have tried makes the test wait the length of time it should.  Rather than shutting the entire process down for that long I implement a loop and check every second:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        long secondsPassed = 0;

        while(!condition && secondsPassed < 10)
        {
            secondsPassed = (System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000;
            logger.trace("secondsPassed=" + secondsPassed);

            //Code here


            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } 

            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

It's a bit of a hack but the only wait I can get selenium to be both responsive to what is happening and wait reliably.  Of course you can tweak the wait to suit your particular needs.

Comment: thanks for your time. For now i think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using some default function of Selenium:

```
 /***
 * An expectation for checking WebElement with given locator has text with a value as a part of it
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param pattern - used as expected text matcher pattern
 * @param timeout
 * @return Boolean true when element has text value containing @value
 */
public boolean textMatches(By locator, Pattern pattern, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textMatches(locator, pattern));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking WebElement with given locator has specific text
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param value - used as expected text
 * @param timeout
 * @return Boolean true when element has text value equal to @value
 */
public boolean textToBe(By locator, String value, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(locator, value));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified element.
 * @param element - the WebElement
 * @param text - to be present in the element
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the element contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElement(WebElement element, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the element that matches the given locator.
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param text - to be present in the element found by the locator
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the first element located by locator contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElementLocated(By locator, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(locator, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified elements value attribute.
 * @param locator - used to find the element
 * @param text - to be present in the value attribute of the element found by the locator
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the value attribute of the first element located by locator contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElementValue(By locator, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(locator, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/***
 * An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified elements value attribute.
 * @param element - the WebElement
 * @param text - to be present in the element's value attribute
 * @param timeout
 * @return true once the element's value attribute contains the given text
 */
public boolean textToBePresentInElementValue(WebElement element, String text, int timeout) {
    try {
        return getWebDriverFluentWait(timeout)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(element, text));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

with

```
private Wait<WebDriver> getWebDriverFluentWait(int timeout) {
    return new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
}
```

Or with another option:

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)    
.withTimeout(30, SECONDS)    
.pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)   
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {    
public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {    
    return driver.findElement(By.id("foo")).getText().length > 0;    
}
});
```

Comment: all of these function require a predefined text which i do not have

Comment: I added another option to the answer