# Wait for the element to be selected in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

There is a text field which gets automatically populated after a certain time by the website and the the text cursor moves to the same text field

```html
<html>
<div>
<input type=text id=name>Enter here</div>
<html>
```

the input field gets selected and filled automatically by the website after a few seconds. I want selenium to wait till it gets selected and then carry on with the further code.
I've done:

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
element=driver.find_element_by_id("name")
wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_selected(element))
```

It throws error even though the text field is filled by the website.

Comment: The info you provided is not enough to answer this question. Add a link to the page or place html code to your question body.

Comment: _the input field gets selected and filled automatically by the website_ - what is the time for this and how much you want to wait ?

Comment: @cruisepandey it normally takes about 3 to 4 seconds. But i dont want to implicitly wait because even if it takes 10 seconds its fine. i cannot proceed without filled text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few answers on other similiar questions which seem to work for respective questions. I did not find anything for python though.
What i did is run an infinite loop until the text present in the element had  length not equal to zero.

```
while 1 is not 5:
    if len(element.get_attribute("value")) is not 0:
          break
    else:
          continue
```

*value* attribute of *element* has the value of whatever string is present in the textfield.

Answer (score 0):

The `expected_conditions.element_to_be_selected()` follows this [spec](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#is-element-selected). Specifically:

> This operation only makes sense on input elements of the **Checkbox- and Radio Button** states (emphasis mine)

Your input is of type text, so it will not work.

You will have to use a different approach. Perhaps something like:

1. Read the text (the `@value` attribute).
2. Wait until it changes to anything else.

Comment: there IS an element attribute of textfield whose value gets changed from "" to whatever the website has entered. But i have not been able to figure out how to use such explicit wait with if statement where i can do "if attribute is true"

Comment: Sounds like you need to Google how to create [Custom Wait Conditions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: there is a same question     "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656252/wait-till-text-present-in-text-field" but it is in java,   can you help me with the python version. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Python.